# How to disable default commandline option -help for custom applications?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible, to disable the default option `-help` for an un-/installer or custom install4j application? Our main application uses this option as well and the commandline parameter will not be passed throught to the application when a custom application (update check) is started before the main application. Instead the help dialog is shown. Now I need to delete or suppress this option so the parameter can be handled by the main application. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance
Hardie

Comment: How is your update checker configured, blocking at startup and in-process? Not sure how the command line arguments of your main method should be affected by the update checker.

Comment: We implemented a custom application to check the update site for a new version (`update.xml`) and if the version is up-to-date the _Execute Launcher_ action is triggered to start the main application. The commandline arguments for our main application are set by `context.getExtraCommandLineArguments()` and here I think the parameter is not pass through. Or maybe the `-help` option blocks the custom application from beeing executed so the launcher will not be started? Also we want to avoid to see the help dialog by starting our application. Application chain: update-check --starts--> launcher

Comment: So you always start your application through a custom installer application? In that case, you cannot use the `-help` argument or a number of other command line arguments.